# Cannot Save Products to the Database

Tags: mongodb, express, react-redux

This is my github repo of simple shopping cart app.I created a simple shopping cart using React-Redux and express.js and I used mongodb for database, but my product are not storing into the database. Please help me
https://github.com/PukarHub/shopping-cart

Comment: I have products and i need to store the cart products in database but it is not working , help me out

Comment: Questions need to be able to stand on their own without external links, since those tend to change.  Please edit the question to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok @Joe i will add a minimal code